# What is the point of offering a salary up to X?

Tags: salary, job-offer

On a job posting it said, a salary up to 60,000.
As a starter I know thats not the salary I will be receiving.

So what is the point of putting any number in there at all? They could offer me up to a million. 
This just mean they be paying me anything between minimum wage an a million.

I also doubt the is a hard cap on the salary. If I turn out the be the second Elon musk and make the company tons of money, then they wil certainly pay me more then 60,000 to keep me.

So is it just a nice number to catch my attention? Or is there a logic behind it?

Comment: _"If I turn out the be the second Elon musk"_ - then you wouldn't be an employee..

Comment: If you know you'll earn less than 60,000 and are okay with that, the notice wasn't intended for you. Your million dollar example actually proves the point: the second Elon Musk would probably still skip the "up to a million" posting since they're expecting to earn more than that.

Comment: Could someone explain their down vote?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to work for less than X it means you can skip this offer.

If you find X a good compensation then you know you know you can apply to the offer and expect a proper compensation.

Comment: In addition it keeps the companies options open to pay you less if they want.  So they may come back with something like "you don't have the amount of experience we were hoping for and you don't have X skill which we would have to train you in but we think you are a good candidate otherwise and would be willing to pay you 50k"

Comment: I might find X a good compensation, but they might offer half (which is not the proper compensation I was expecting).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the amount of value someone can contribute to a company in a given job is capped at a certain level for most jobs. Even if you are the next Elon Musk you cannot earn the company millions if you are employed as a bookkeeper for a small/midsized company.
Therefore having a hard cap on a salary makes perfect sense.

Putting a high "up-to-X" salary indeed can serve as an eye-catcher, making people more likely to respond. In the final negotiation stages the company can always (try to) renegotiate a lower offer because the candidate doesn't have X,Y or Z.